# Application force close with this error when app opens

Tags: android, forceclose

this is my activity code:

```
package com.microweb.gapiha;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.TabHost;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //keep screen on and alive
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("social").setContent(new    Intent(this  ,IntroActivity.class )));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("chat").setContent(new Intent(this ,ChatActivity.class )));           
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("sevom").setIndicator("new chat").setContent(new Intent(this ,RandomActivity.class )));             
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);  
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager  = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
}
```

and this is log:

http://s4.picofile.com/file/7855602903/err.png

when I run project in emulator or in my devices , it's show force
close error... why? before I run this project and no have any error but
now,... I do not do any changes...

this is xml code:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pB1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="2dip" />
```

Comment: post your xml and why have you commented `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Comment: Please don't include error messages as link to an image or as an image. This should be included as **text** in your question!

Comment: Why do you include code for `isNetworkAvailable`, if you don't use it? It can't be the cause if you don't use it, so remove it from the question.

Comment: have you declared TasbHost inside xml ?

Comment: i declar it with code in activity